# How to trace a line and make it thicker

Tags: c#, svg, graphics

I have an app that has the user write their signature.  This is saved as an svg in javascript and sent back to the server.  The server then crops the whitespace outside the actual signature.  If someone signs a small signature then when the white space is cropped the image is scaled and the lines become thicker.  If someone uses the whole signature box then the lines are very thin.  Is there a way to trace the signature if someone uses the whole signature box and make the lines thicker?

Maybe there's a whole different way of looking at this problem that I don't see right now.  I have inherited this code and I am not very familiar with graphics especially in javascript.  The signature is using paper.js to allow the user to sign and maybe there is something that can be done there?

Comment: `SVG` = `Scalable Vector Graphic` <-- that's why they appear "thinner" when the canvas is larger, and "thicker" when it is smaller.

Comment: I know this... I'm just trying to fulfill requirements... They want to crop the white space and scale the image but they don't like how thin the lines are when you use the whole canvas.  I need to figure out a way to make the line sizes consistent no matter how much of the canvas a user uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to retrace the signature.  Just rescale the `stroke-width` attribute based on the new cropped width.

For example, if the user uses the whole box, leave the `stroke-width` alone.  If they only use half the box, then when you do the crop, halve the value of the `stroke-width`. So when it is scaled up, the lines look the same.

You don't say how the signatures are stored on the server.  Are they kept as SVG, or converted to bitmap?

Comment: The scaling is done after the image has been converted to a bitmap. I'll see if I can figure out how to scale it as an svg

Comment: @Tbonebrad If you crop it before the stroke is applied, then when you do apply the wider stroke, part of it would be clipped anyways. What you probably want to do is find out how large of a reduction would be made with the current stroke. Increase the stroke, then recalculate the crop dimensions and apply them.